# Is there anyway to get Instagram Highlights via API?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

I'm looking for a way to get Instagram Highlights via API. I known that Instagram has an endpoint to get Story (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/ig-user/stories/), but it only returns last 24 hours stories. So, any chance to get stories longer than 24hrs?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try out this API:

`https://i.instagram.com/api/v1/feed/reels_media/?reel_ids=highlight%{highlighId}`

Answer (score 0):

Can't beat instaloader. It's a python package that let's you download stories, feeds, highlights, reels, and more. And it can do it all in a single run.

https://instaloader.github.io/basic-usage.html